# Do clothing, jetpacks and vehicle upgrades help you in Jetpack Joyride?

Tags: jetpack-joyride

Do clothing, jetpacks and vehicle upgrades help you in Jetpack Joyride or are they purely for aesthetics?

Comment: There are now Gadgets which have special effects, some which help you get more Final Spin tokens, more coins or more rides.

Answer (score 8):

Out of clothing, jetpacks, and vehicle upgrades only the following provide any actual tangible benefit:

- Hog Magnet
- Stomper Magnet
- Teleporter Magnet
- Bird Magnet
- Gravity Suit Magnet
- Mr. Cuddles Magnet (added in the Oct./Nov. 2011 update)

The benefit of any of the Magnet items is that they attract coins that are close by without having to touch them. The clothing and jetpack upgrades provide only an aesthetic benefits, although some of them do help toward gaining certain Achievements.

Comment: Don't forget about the Mr. Cuddles magnet!

Comment: @DaveK thanks for the heads up, forgot about the update.

Comment: so i guess the golden vehicles don't do anything?

Comment: @Kip not as far as I've seen. Just for show. The descriptions for each state the same.

Comment: Don't forget the surfer magnet!

Answer (score 6):

The Golden Piggy Pack jetpack is powered by firing $1000 bills. I noticed that unlike other jetpacks, scientists will run toward the bills making it easier to high five.

Comment: Also worth noting that if you have a mission to get to X meters without harming scientists, the piggy bank can help since it's one of the jetpacks whose projectiles don't hit scientists. The rainbow jetpack doesn't harm scientists as well

Comment: Its much easier just to use nerd repellent for those missions though.