# What is the point of getting the golden vehicles in jetpack joyride?

Tags: jetpack-joyride

What do golden verhicles do for you, except cost a lot of money? So far I've only upgraded Mr. Snuggles (or whatever the dragon is called) to gold, and the only difference that I noted besides the golden color was, that it now reaches more into the screen which actually makes it harder to use, since you have less time to spot zappers coming at you?!

Comment: are you sure the golden mr snuggles takes up more screen real estate and its not because of your current speed?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/29598/do-clothing-jetpacks-and-vehicle-upgrades-help-you-in-jetpack-joyride

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Other than the fact that you get to ride shinier vehicles, there is a secret achievement that is unlocked when you purchase your first gold vehicle (which you've already done).  Its called [Blinged Out](http://jetpackjoyride.wikia.com/wiki/Blinged_Out).

Gold vehicles should be no different from the regular ones.

Answer (score 4):

The Golden vehicles are no different aside from the visual effects (they are reflective gold all over and sparkle a bit). There's no functional difference, the only practical use is to get an achievement (at least I believe there was an achievement for buying one of them).

They shouldn't take up more of the screen either though, They're just re-skinned.

Answer (score 0):

Aside from the fact that you get an achievement for it, it makes the game more appealing to the eyes. It also makes you feel like you've progressed further in the game, and it's also a way to show off to your friends.

Answer (score -1):

Actually, I've counted the coin set and it gives a few more coins than a regular vehicle. You'll eventually get the total cost back.

Comment: For what version and platform?  The Jetpack Joyride wikia used to claim that it gave more coins, but it no longer does (http://jetpackjoyride.wikia.com/wiki/Vehicles), and I personally have never seen evidence of this on the Android version.